# Página não lista itens

Tags: java, jsf

Por algum motivo a página XHTML não lista os itens de `#{nomesMB.nomes}`. Códigos:

---

**XHTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Lista de nomes</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
                Nome: <h:inputText value="#{nomesMB.nome}" binding="#{nomesMB.inputNome}"/>
            <br />
            <h:commandButton value="Adicionar" 
            action="#{nomesMB.adicionar()}" binding="#{nomesMB.botaoAdicionar}"/>
            <br />
            <ol>
                <ui:repeat var="nome" value="#{nomesMB.nomes}">
                    <li>#{nome}</li>
                </ui:repeat>
            </ol>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

---

**Java**:

```
package br.com.marciowillian.financeiro.managedbean;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlCommandButton;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="nomesMB")
@ViewScoped
public class NomesBean {
    private String nome;
    private List<String> nomes =  new ArrayList<>();

    private HtmlInputText inputNome;
    private HtmlCommandButton botaoAdicionar;

    public void adicionar() {
        this.nomes.add(nome);

        //desativa campo botao quando mais de 3 nomes forem adicionados
        if(this.nomes.size() > 3) {
            this.inputNome.setDisabled(true);
            this.botaoAdicionar.setDisabled(true);
            this.botaoAdicionar.setValue("Muitos nomes adicionados...");
        }

    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public List<String> getNomes() {
        return nomes;
    }

    public HtmlInputText getInputNome() {
        return inputNome;
    }

    public void setInputNome(HtmlInputText inputNome) {
        this.inputNome = inputNome;
    }

    public HtmlCommandButton getBotaoAdicionar() {
        return botaoAdicionar;
    }

    public void setBotaoAdicionar(HtmlCommandButton botaoAdicionar) {
        this.botaoAdicionar = botaoAdicionar;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionei o problema.

Eu estava selecionando o escopo do ManagedBean diferente do que precisava.
O escopo correto era o `@SessionScoped`.

Alterei o escopo e funcionou.

Comment: Marque sua resposta como solução, por favor.